# Find next visit date after discharge in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find the next visit date after a discharge but when I do it is only showing the next visit after the first discharge of 9/12 as shown below under "Have". I would like it to show what appears in "Want". I have tried joining to VISIT table where visit.service_date is greater than admits.discharge_date and then taking the MIN of service_date but that is what returns in "Have".

Have:

| id_num | admit_date | discharge_date | next_visit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100000005 | 8/25/2022 | 9/1/2022 | 9/12/2022 |
| 100000005 | 10/15/2022 | 10/22/2022 | 9/12/2022 |
| 100000005 | 10/22/2022 | 11/22/2022 | 9/12/2022 |

Want:

| id_num | admit_date | discharge_date | next_visit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100000005 | 8/25/2022 | 9/1/2022 | 9/12/2022 |
| 100000005 | 10/15/2022 | 10/22/2022 |  |
| 100000005 | 10/22/2022 | 11/22/2022 | 11/28/2022 |

```
CREATE TABLE ADMITS
(
ID_NUM INT
,ADMIT_DATE DATE NULL
,DISCHARGE_DATE DATE NULL
)

INSERT INTO ADMITS (ID_NUM, ADMIT_DATE, DISCHARGE_DATE)
VALUES
 (100000005, '8/25/2022', '9/1/2022')
,(100000005, '10/15/2022', '10/22/2022')
,(100000005, '10/22/2022', '11/22/2022');
```

```
CREATE TABLE VISITS
(
ID_NUM INT
,SERVICE_DATE DATE NULL
,PROVIDER_ID INT NULL
,SVCOD VARCHAR(10) NULL
)

INSERT INTO VISITS(ID_NUM, SERVICE_DATE, PROVIDER_ID,SVCOD)
VALUES
 (100000005, '9/12/2022', 903263,'T1015')
,(100000005, '10/24/2022', 903263,'T1015')
,(100000005, '11/7/2022', 903263,'T1015')
,(100000005, '11/28/2022', 903263,'T1015');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your sample data (you insert into ADMITS in BOTH inserts).

Also, why is next_visit blank in your second WANT row?

Anyways, I assume you want to do something like this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ADMITS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS VISITS;

CREATE TABLE ADMITS
(
ID_NUM INT
,ADMIT_DATE DATE NULL
,DISCHARGE_DATE DATE NULL
)

INSERT INTO ADMITS (ID_NUM, ADMIT_DATE, DISCHARGE_DATE)
VALUES
 (100000005, '8/25/2022', '9/1/2022')
,(100000005, '10/15/2022', '10/22/2022')
,(100000005, '10/22/2022', '11/22/2022');



CREATE TABLE VISITS
(
ID_NUM INT
,SERVICE_DATE DATE NULL
,PROVIDER_ID INT NULL
,SVCOD VARCHAR(10) NULL
)

INSERT INTO VISITS (ID_NUM, SERVICE_DATE, PROVIDER_ID,SVCOD)
VALUES
 (100000005, '9/12/2022', 903263,'T1015')
,(100000005, '10/24/2022', 903263,'T1015')
,(100000005, '11/7/2022', 903263,'T1015')
,(100000005, '11/28/2022', 903263,'T1015');


SELECT A.*, (SELECT MIN(SERVICE_DATE) 
             FROM VISITS AS V 
             WHERE V.ID_NUM = A.ID_NUM 
               AND SERVICE_DATE > DISCHARGE_DATE) AS next_visit 
FROM ADMITS AS A
;
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I was going to have the second one blank since the admit and discharge were on same day but that might be a data issue.